# Displaying multiple location on google map android

Tags: android, arrays, google-maps, android-emulator, geolocation

I have an array of addresses and I wanna show them on the map (I know direction is not possible) . I use INTENT but it only displays 1 address! How can I make it show all addresses
Here is my code:

```
    for(int j=0; j<jarElements.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject distanceObj = jarElements.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("distance");
                        distanceStr = distanceObj.getString("value");
                        Log.v("finally getting distance : ", distanceStr);
                        buff.append("Distace from the location " + Addresses[j] + " is : " + distanceStr).append("\n").append("\n");
                        Intent is = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + Addresses[j] + "&daddr=" + distanceStr));
startActivity(Is);
```

Comment: check this : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Answer (score 0):

What you did here will fire a request to Google Map application to get direction from `Addresses[j]` to `distanceStr`, and this will turn on the Google Maps application in return with the direction orders.
This is the normal behavior for the Intent you wrote.

AFAIK there is no way to show directions to multiple locations from android. It's can be done from the Google Maps web service.